# htaccess not working but check successful localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a simple .htaccessfile

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v4r.info/(.*)/(.*) v4r.info/NGOplus/index.php?NGO=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I tested the file in htaccess.madewithlove.com, it gives a correct result and copy&pasting the result works flawlessly. (http://localhost/v4r.info/NGOplus/index.php?NGO=action-for-woman&page=board.list.php&ff=710;;;;;&startdate=2017-11-11)

But htaccess fails on localhost with an error:

```
File does not exist:
/var/www/html/public_html/v4r.info/action-for-woman/board.list.php
```

The test URL is

localhost/v4r.info/NGOplus/index.php?NGO=action-for-woman&page=board.list.php&ff=710;;;;;&startdate=2017-11-11

- htaccess is active. (rubbish line gives "internal server error")
- in another directory htaccess is working fine.
- apache.conf seems ok (AllowOverride All)

Added:

The htaccess file is not in the base directory but in the 1. subdirectory (v4r.info).

What works is htaccess in v4r.info/NGOplus with a symlink 'action-for-woman' to NGOplus
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]

Here, apache does a «local» rewrite, i.e. just the last part of the URL (the directory name 'action-for-woman' I have to extract from $_SERVER ...)

Comment: "The test URL is..." - don't you mean the test URL is `localhost/v4r.info/action-for-woman/board.list.php?ff=710;;;;;&startdate=2017-11-11`? A potential issue with the rule you've posted is that it would rewrite itself (although that shouldn't be an issue in this instance) and would also be an issue when requesting the target URL directly (but you say it's not).

Comment: I think it is a sign that apache does not do any rewriting. But anyhow, rewriting is not recursive afaik.

Comment: my .htaccess file is in v4r.info directory what is not the root directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my .htaccess file is in v4r.info directory what is not the root directory.

In that case, your rule will never match. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches a URL-path relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file.

> But anyhow, rewriting is not recursive afaik.

Yes, it is "recursive" in a *directory* context (ie. `.htaccess`). In that the rewrite engine "loops" repeatedly until the URL passes through unchanged, or you have explicitly set `END` (Apache 2.4).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /v4r.info/NGOplus/index.php?NGO=$1&page=$2 [L,QSA]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure that only direct requests are rewritten and not already rewritten requests.

However, this pattern is still far too generic as it matches any two path segments. I put the 2nd condition that checks `index.php` just so you can request `/v4r.info/NGOplus/index.php` directly (as you were doing in your tests). However, this could be avoided by making the regex more specific.

Comment: It did not work until I removed the symlink directory 'action-for-woman' (pointing to NGOplus). But after removing this link it works

Comment: What seems strange: <dir>/<file> does not work when dir is a symlink pointing to NGOplus. dir being an empty directory does not prevent the rewriting.